# svn: Error parsing svn:externals property on '.'

Tags: svn, svn-externals

If I do

svn propset svn:externals 'https://url.to.remote.branch' .

svn: Error parsing svn:externals property on '.' : 'https://url.to.remote.branch'

If I do

svn propedit svn:externals 'https://url.to.remote.branch' .

::vi - enter message::

svn: Error parsing svn:externals property on 'https://url.to.remote.branch': 'message'

Any ideas?  I haven't been able to google/find the instance of this problem happening on '.'

Comment: svn propset svn:externals 'branch-dir https://url.to.remote.branch' .

Comment: You should submit that as an answer to this question and accept it so that it's more obvious that it's been answered (correctly) -- and so this isn't still an open question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

svn propset svn:externals 'branch-dir url.to.remote.branch';